# Unable to start SDL Tridion Content Manager Search Host

Tags: sites-9

We are unable to start SDL Tridion Content Manager Search Host,  it is giving the following error

> some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other
>   services or programs

[image]

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you install sites 9 or you did upgrade , did you check the event logs and can you provide more details

Comment: check this link ( https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=Tridion-Content-Manager-Search-Host-service-does-not-start
)

Comment: We installed sites 9 and it worked till yesterday but suddenly it stopped. Unfortunately we could not find any logs in event viewer and Parameters is already exists in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\TcmSearchHost as suggested in KB article.

Comment: can you check the system logs and provide more details

Answer (score 1):

It is working fine after remove AppDynamics settings from the procrun startup parameters (regedit, key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\TcmSearchHost\Parameters\Start

Comment: good its working